# Finding complex number given argument and modulus

Tags: complex-numbers

So I have to find the complex number, and I know it's modulus is 2 and its argument is 3pi/4. Does this mean the complex number is z= sqrt(2)/2-sqrt(2)/2i

Comment: If $~r \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ and $~\theta \in \Bbb{R},~$ then the complex number given by $$z = re^{i\theta} = r \times [ ~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) ~]$$ will have a modulus (i.e. absolute value) of $~r~$ and an argument of $~\theta.~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It would be
$ 2(cos(3\pi/4)+i sin(3\pi/4)) = 2(-1/\sqrt{2}+i/\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}$